# Counts from another table don't exist yet to filter in WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions

I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> [42703] ERROR: column "nonprimarycount" does not exist
> ```

With this query:

```
SELECT
  d.id,
  COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE s.is_primary = True) AS primarycount,
  COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE s.is_primary = False) AS nonprimarycount
FROM Dino d
LEFT JOIN Senator s ON d.id = s.id
WHERE nonprimarycount < 10
GROUP BY d.id
ORDER BY nonprimarycount DESC, 
            primarycount DESC;
```

It's clear to me that I can't do this because the `nonprimarycount` I made doesn't exist yet, but it's not clear to me how to do this correctly. I'd like to select only records with fewer than 10 nonprimary counts, and I need to construct that count in the query.

Comment: Unrelated, but: if you assumed that `count(1)´ is faster than `count(*)` you were wrong.

Comment: Is it /slower/ or just no difference and a silly way to write that?

Comment: Oh, I see this is contentious https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1-sql-server

Comment: https://blog.jooq.org/2019/09/19/whats-faster-count-or-count1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT d.id,
       COUNT(1) FILTER (s.is_primary) AS primarycount,
       COUNT(1) FILTER (NOT s.is_primary) AS nonprimarycount
FROM Dino d LEFT JOIN
     Senator s ON d.id = s.id
GROUP BY d.id
HAVING COUNT(1) FILTER (NOT s.is_primary) < 10 
ORDER BY nonprimarycount desc, 
            primarycount desc;
```

I think Postgres requires that you repeat the expression, rather than using the column alias.

Answer (score 2):

You error is `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`, like Gordon pointed out.

But I suggest to rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT id
     , COALESCE(s.primarycount   , 0) AS    primarycount
     , COALESCE(s.nonprimarycount, 0) AS nonprimarycount
FROM   dino d
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT id
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE is_primary) AS primarycount
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE is_primary = false) AS nonprimarycount
   FROM   senator
   GROUP  BY id
   ) s USING (id)
WHERE  (s.nonprimarycount > 9) IS NOT TRUE
ORDER  BY nonprimarycount DESC, primarycount DESC;
```

Should be faster.

- It's typically (much) faster to aggregate *before* the join.
- Since we pushed the aggregation down into a subquery, we can now use `WHERE` in the outer `SELECT` instead of `HAVING`, removing your cause of error. Same performance, but simpler.
- `count(*)` is faster and equivalent for the case.
- `is_primary = true` is a noisy way of saying `is_primary`.
- `WHERE (s.nonprimarycount > 9) IS NOT TRUE` is the same as `WHERE (s.nonprimarycount < 10 OR s.nonprimarycount IS NULL)`.
- We can now get NULL for "no row in table `senator`". I default to `0` like your original does. If you want to display the difference instead, remove `COALESCE` and use `ORDER BY ... DESC NULLS LAST` to sort NULL values last.
- Notably, the (unqualified!) output column name will work in `ORDER BY`, even though it's the same as the input column name in the outer `SELECT` because, [quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY):

> If an `ORDER BY` expression is a simple name that matches both an
> output column name and an input column name, `ORDER BY` will interpret
> it as the output column name. This is the opposite of the choice that
> `GROUP BY` will make in the same situation. This inconsistency is made
> to be compatible with the SQL standard.

**If** we can assume that every `dino` has at least one row in `senator`, we can simplify:

```sql
SELECT id
     , s.primarycount
     , s.nonprimarycount
FROM   dino d
JOIN  (
   SELECT id
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE is_primary) AS primarycount
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE is_primary = false) AS nonprimarycount
   FROM   senator
   GROUP  BY id
   ) s USING (id)
WHERE  s.nonprimarycount < 10
ORDER  BY s.nonprimarycount DESC, s.primarycount DESC;
```

Now, the counts cannot be NULL.